# "%w(foo, bar)" constructs in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I [stumbled](https://github.com/cromwellryan/sweetelixir/blob/master/advanced/pipeline.md) upon the `%w(foo, bar)` construct in Elixir.

I can't find any reference to it in the current docs, and google is not helping either.
It [looks like](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1394) it was part of the language in 2013.

Can anyone point me to the documentation and maybe show an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elixir provides [sigils](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html). As explained in the docs, sigils *are one of the mechanisms provided by the language for working with textual representations*.

Prior to v1, Elixir sigil syntax was very similar to Ruby. Specifically, the following line:

```
%w( foo bar )
```

produced a [word list](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#word-lists).

The syntax of sigils was [changed in 2014](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/ba54afbf45a89546cdd1a220eb1b3a2fc58e69da) and it is now prefixed by `~` instead of `%`:

```
~w( foo bar )
```

Comment: Thank you, And do you know why `iex` seems to accept it, and hangs instead of raising an error?

Comment: Ok, I've managed to find the entry in the changelog: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v0.12.5